# jasper report error condition error

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a problem with this code below. It is a five conditions operation.
When it goes to fourth condition `($F{field}.equals("text here4"))` it reads that line: `$F{total}.doubleValue()*Double.valueOf(100)/Double.valueOf(220`), 
and make available even for fifth condition.

```
$F{field}.equals("text here1")
? $F{total}.doubleValue()*Double.valueOf(100)/Double.valueOf(360)
:$F{field}.equals("another text here2")
? $F{total}.doubleValue()*Double.valueOf(100)/Double.valueOf(390)
:$F{field}.equals("text here3")
? $F{total}.doubleValue()*Double.valueOf(100)/Double.valueOf(190)
:$F{field}.equals("text here4")
? $F{total}.doubleValue()*Double.valueOf(100)/Double.valueOf(290)
:$F{total}.doubleValue()*Double.valueOf(100)/Double.valueOf(220)
```

When i use JasperiF:

```
new JasperIf().
jif($F{cond}.equalsIgnoreCase("")).jthen("!")
.jelseif($F{cond}.equalsIgnoreCase(""), "!")
.jelseif($F{cond}.equalsIgnoreCase(""), "!")
.jelse("")
```

i got the error: jasper if type cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: i read it over here [link](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/if-else-in-jasper-reports-expressions/) and i thought it was a jasper report syntax. sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JasperReport org.w3c.tools.codec.Base64Decoder cannot be resolved to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48875851/jasperreport-org-w3c-tools-codec-base64decoder-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)

Answer (score 0):

Is your condition running only for fifth condition? If yes:

Can you please check your `$F{field}` for extra spaces? Also check for case sensitivity the word you are using in `.equals("check this")`.

Comment: to have a clear idea:

`$F{field}.equals("text here1")
? $F{total}.doubleValue()*Double.valueOf(100)/Double.valueOf(360)
:$F{field}.equals("another text here2")
? $F{total}.doubleValue()*Double.valueOf(100)/Double.valueOf(390)
:$F{field}.equals("text here3")
? $F{total}.doubleValue()*Double.valueOf(100)/Double.valueOf(190)
:$F{field}.equals("text here4")
? $F{total}.doubleValue()*Double.valueOf(100)/Double.valueOf(290)
:$F{field}.equals("text here5")
?$F{total}.doubleValue()*Double.valueOf(100)/Double.valueOf(220)
:"null" `
But this one doesn't work, doesn't read the fifth condition

Comment: is it possible that $F{field} can be null ? if yes you have to handle that condition too. otherwise it will not work.

Comment: i solved it guys, just change the places between the true code (?) and false code (:)

thank you for your time